# HBase: Why do I need to disable a table before dropping it?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, distributed-computing

I know that before dropping a table in HBase, I must disable it.
What is the reasoning behind this? What does disabling do in HBase that allows a table to be dropped?

In other words, why can't I delete/drop a table without disabling it?

Comment: disable is basically "notifying" the Region Servers (the machines hosting the table data) that the table is going to be removed. once no one is hosting the table data, you can ask the master to drop the table metadata. you can implement delete as disable+delete but then it will take a lot longer and then you have to handle the failures. and hbase master is not too good with handling failures in the mid of unassign/disable operations.

Comment: i think it is a design choice, manually locking table to write/reads, in sql world this is called lock table. Nice to have feature, i think :)